# multivariable limit of a piecewise function with a more general hypothesis

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Find $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}f(x,y)$, where $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} 
      \dfrac{\ln(1+xy)}{x} & x\neq0 \\
      y & x=0
   \end{cases}$$

I have a hunch that this has something to do with $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\dfrac{\ln(1+xy)}{x}=\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\dfrac{\ln(1+xy)}{xy}y$ which would be equal to $0$ since $\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{\ln(1+t)}{t}=1$. I shall hypothesize that $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,a)}f(x,y)=a$ .

Is my hypothesis corect? if yes, how do I prove it? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $z \geqslant 0$ we have  $\displaystyle \frac{z}{1+z} \leqslant \ln(1+z)=\int_1^{1+z} \frac{dt}{t} \leqslant z$.

For $z < 0$ we have $\displaystyle -z = |z|\leqslant -\ln(1+z)=-\ln(1 - |z|)= \int_{1 -|z|}^{1} \frac{dt}{t} \leqslant \frac{|z|}{1-|z|} = \frac{-z}{1+z}.$

This implies that regardless of the sign  of $xy$ we have

$$\frac{xy}{1+xy} \leqslant \ln(1+xy) \leqslant xy$$

Thus, $f(x,y) = y$ for $x = 0$ and

$$\frac{y}{1+xy} \leqslant f(x,y) = \frac{\ln(1+xy)}{x} \leqslant y \quad \text{ for } x > 0,\\y \leqslant f(x,y) = \frac{\ln(1+xy)}{x} \leqslant \frac{y}{1+xy} \quad \text{ for } x < 0$$

By the squeeze theorem, it follows that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,a)} f(x,y) = a$ and the hypothesis is correct.

Comment: How does $\frac{z}{1+z} \leqslant \ln(1+z)=\int_1^{1+z} \frac{dt}{t} \leqslant z$ work? Why does $\frac{z}{1+z} \leqslant \ln(1+z)$ and why does $\int_1^{1+z} \frac{dt}{t} \leqslant z$?

Comment: I put $\ln(1+z) =\int_1^{1+z} \frac{dt}{t}$ in the middle just to relate the logarithm and the integral. The bounds come from $1 < t <1+z$.

Comment: So for example $\int_1^{1+z} \frac{dt}{t} > \int_1^{1+z} \frac{dt}{1+z}= \frac{1+z-1}{1+z} =\frac{z}{1+z}$

Comment: By the way, how did you get the intuition for proving $\frac{z}{1+z}\leq\ln(1+z)\leq z$?

Comment: @LeeLaindingold: This is a very well-known and useful inequality.  I showed you one way to prove it (rather than just state it).  There are many other ways, for example when $x > 0$ we have $1+x < e^x$ and, hence,  $\ln(1+x) < x$, etc.